# String formatting with characters is crashing

Tags: ios, swift, string

```
var modifiedString: String {       

    var outString = String()
        for thisChar in self.characters {
            if (thisChar == " "){
                outString.appendingFormat("%%02X",thisChar ) // This line is asking me unwrap as CVarArg
                outString.appendingFormat("%%02X",thisChar as! CVarArg) // This line crashes
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to use `outString.appendingFormat("%%02X",thisChar )`
But this line is forcing me to unwrap as `CVarArg` but it is crashing when I am doing it. what is wrong in this

Comment: What you really want to do? Even if you fixed that error, your code is full of strange things. - missing return. - `appendingFormat` does not modify `outString`, so its value is empty when `for`-loop finished. - the format `"%%02X"` does not consume arguments and generates `"%02X"`. - all characters other than white spcases are ignored.

Comment: Are you trying to convert the ASCII value to a hex number? maybe you should use `.utf8` instead of `.characters`?

Comment: Also, you are encoding only space characters because of that `if thisChar == " "`?

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is placed in a `String` extension.

The error occurs because `Character` does not conform to `CVarArg`. Instead of converting the character directly to `CVarArg`, you need to convert it to a type that conforms to `CVarArg`. Here, the best choice would be `String`:

```
outString.appendingFormat("%%02X", "\(thisChar)")
```

You are also missing a return statement.

However, even if you did this and your code compiles, the property you wrote still does not make much sense. I don't think it works as you intended it to, but without more information I can't really be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code-

```
var modifiedString: String {
        var outString = String()
        for thisChar in self.characters {
            if (thisChar == " "){
                //    outString = outString.appendingFormat("%%02X",thisChar.description )
                outString = outString.appendingFormat("%%02X", "\(thisChar)")

            }
            else
            {
                outString = outString.appending("\(thisChar)")
            }
        }
        return outString
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear enough what you want to do, but I guess you want to do something like this:

```
extension String {
    var modifiedString: String {
        var outString = ""
        for thisChar in self.characters {
            if thisChar == " " {
                let charCode = String(thisChar).unicodeScalars.first!.value
                outString += "%" + String(format: "%02X", charCode)
                //### Or if you prefer... (Do not miss, you need 3 '%'s in the format string.)
                //outString = outString.appendingFormat("%%%02X", charCode)
            } else {
                outString.append(thisChar)
            }
        }
        return outString
    }
}

print("what you really want to do?".modifiedString)
//->what%20you%20really%20want%20to%20do?
```

---

With looping with `for thisChar in self.characters`, the type of `thisChar` becomes `Character`, it's not easy to get a character code from `Character` in Swift.

There may be some better ways but `let charCode = String(thisChar).unicodeScalars.first!.value` works as expected, when `thisChar` contains only one `UnicodeScalar`.

---

And you should better know Swift has a method named `addingPercentEncoding`:

```
let result = "what you really want to do?".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.whitespaces.inverted)!
print(result)
//->what%20you%20really%20want%20to%20do?
```